# Why can't I override an img inside a div?

Tags: css, html

I've been spending a couple of hours and can't seem to figure this out. I have a html tree similar to this:

```
<div class="region">
  <div class="area" id="one">
    <img src="..." />
    <span>...</span>
...
```

Then my css has:

```
.region {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 80%;
}

.area {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}​

.area img {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 0;
}
```

The problem is that for some reason I can't seem to be able to override img inside the area class. When I look into firebug I only see a global img being applied (display: inline-block) and nothing else.

The interesting thing is that replacing the "img" for "span" in the css does override it! How can this happen? Tested for typos, etc. but I can't seem to figure this out.

Any tip greatly appreciated!

Comment: Strange. Do you have a public URL we can peek at?

Comment: Is there an other css selector that has more priority than .area img ?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/UxLuJ/

We'll probably need more complete source to be able to help.

Comment: Unfortunately I have this in localhost. I'll start disabling other divs to see if something changes. Perhaps something I ommited here is where the problem is.

Comment: What happens if you change ".area img" to "#one img" in the CSS?

Comment: @kol: Already tried it, but no difference. What puzzles me is that replacing with 'span' works fine.. I've been looking up to the root of the tree but don't see any other img being declared.

Comment: Hmmm... isn't there a "#one img" rule in your CSS accidentally?

Comment: This is very weird. I just added the .country img in firebug and it was accepted ok. How can it be then that it's not processed correctly from my css file?

Answer (score 1):

I see the same issue in Firefox 16.02, and the latest Safari and Chrome. However, adding a class to the image fixes it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .region {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      padding: 0;
      width: 80%;
    }
    .area {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      width: 25%;
    }​
    .area img {
      border: 1px solid green;
      margin: 0;
    }    
    .area .place {
        border: 1px solid purple;
    }
    </style>
    <title>Hello Dolly!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="region">
        <div class="area" id="one">
            <img src="../Pictures/TheBridge.jpg" class="place">
            <span>Span This</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Carl, good to see I'm not alone into this. Unfortunately your fix doesn't work in my case (using Chrome Version 23.0.1271.64 on Ubuntu) but this is enough to start suspecting there could be some bug making this happen. Will keep on looking.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem causing it, though I don't understand why this is happening. My original css selectors look like this:

```
.area {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}​

.area img {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 0;
}

.area span {
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

With this order, the code doesn't work and img is completely ignored, but span isn't.

Now if I swap img with span, leaving the order .area, .area span, .area img then span is ignored, but img isn't!

Does anybody have any idea what could be causing this? I never ran into this kind of issue.

Comment: Can you show what you have inside span  which says ...  Does the span has another inside it .. Copy the whole HTML inside the region class

Comment: Span contains some fixed text: <span>France</span>

Comment: @Dan.. Can you recreate this issue in a fiddle .?

Comment: Problem is that it works fine in a fiddle: see http://jsfiddle.net/UxLuJ/1/ for latest version. But for some reason on my browser it doesn't override the img.

Answer (score 0):

Could someone please try this http://jsfiddle.net/UxLuJ/1/ on a real browser to see if you can reproduce the problem?

In my case, using Chrome Version 23.0.1271.64 and Firefox 16.0.2 the img tag isn't parsed correctly. A way to fix the problem is doing the following: add a dummy selector between .country and .country img like this:

```
.country .foo {}
```

This way, the img tag is recognized correctly.

This seems to be the same bug reported by Carl, though I use a slightly different workaround.

I'd appreciate someone else confirming this.